# CEP for Abelian groups and lattices

Tags: abelian-groups, lattice-orders, congruence-relations

An algebra $A$ has the congruence extension property (CEP) if for every $B\le A$ and $\theta \in \operatorname{Con} B$ there is a $\phi \in \operatorname{Con} A$ such that $\theta = \phi \cap (B\times B)$. A class $K$ of algebras has the CEP if every algebra in the class has the CEP.

I must show that the class of Abelian groups has the CEP and find an example of lattice that doesn't have the CEP.

For Abelian groups: 
I consider it doing by induction on number of elements in a group and use inductive proposition on quotient groups. This is just an idea and I don't know how to use it.

Lattices:
I know that counterexample for lattices should be some non distributive lattice because all distributive are CEP. But I can't find any example of congruence in a sublattice that wouldn't be also a subset of a congruence of a lattice. Maybe my understanding of basic terms isn't correct...

Tnx in advance for any help

Comment: What is "con B"?

Comment: "conB" is the set of all congruences on an algebra B

Comment: Similar question at another forum: http://www.sosmath.com/CBB/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=62177

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[$M_3$ is a simple lattice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149494/m-3-is-a-simple-lattice), which means it has only two congruences. But if you omit one element you'll get a "square" $\mathcal P(\{0,1\})$, which has a non-trivial congruence.

Congruences in groups correspond to normal subgroups. So [CEP property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CEP_subgroup) only means that every normal subgroup of $B$ is an intersection of a normal subgroup of $A$ with the subgroup $B$. In Abelian groups, every subgroup is normal; so in the Abelian case this property is trivial.

Comment: Every intersection will be a normal subgroup. But I don't see how we exhaust all possible normal subgroups of B using this argument.

Comment: @AnuragSharma If $H$ is a subgroup of $B$, then $H$ is also subgroup of $A$. So we get $H=H\cap B$, i.e., we expressed $H$ as an intersection of a subgroup of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Oh. M really sorry for such a silly question. Thanks