# CEP for (distributive) lattices and groups?

Tags: group-theory, lattice-orders, universal-algebra, congruence-relations

An algebra $A$ has the congruence extension property (CEP) if for every $B\le A$ and $\theta\in\operatorname{Con}(B)$ there is a $\varphi\in\operatorname{Con}(A)$ such that $\theta =\varphi\cap(B\times B)$. A class $K$ of algebras has the CEP if every algebra in the class has the CEP.

- Does the class of all lattices has CEP?
- Does the class of all groups has CEP?
- Does the class of all distributive lattices has CEP?

Comment: What is the definition of $\operatorname{Con}(A)$?

Comment: Since in groups congruences correspond to normal subgroups, what you are asking for groups would be that given a group $G$, and a subgroup $H$, if $N\triangleleft H$ then there exists $M\triangleleft G$ such that $M\cap H=N$. It is now easy to see that this does not hold, for example by taking $G=A_5$ which is simple, but all of whose proper subgroups that are not of prime order are not simple.

Comment: @SantanaAfton: A congruence on $A$ is an equivalence relation on $A$ which, when viewed as a subset of $A\times A$, is also a subalgebra of $A\times A$ (with the induced structure); they are the objects that play the role of normal subgroups for groups and ideals for rings, to define quotients. $\mathrm{Con}(A)$ is the collection of all congruences on $A$.

Comment: related (possibly duplicate) question: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177997/cep-for-abelian-groups-and-lattices?rq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variety of all groups does not have the property. Congruences correspond to normal subgroups, so you are essentially asking whether if $H\leq G$, and $N\triangleleft H$, does there always exist an $M\triangleleft G$ such that $M\cap H= N$. This does not hold; for example, if $G=A_5$, $H=A_4$, and $N$ is a nontrivial proper normal subgroup of $A_4$, then you cannot find any appropriate $M$.

The variety of all latices does not have the property either. Let $L$ be the nondistributive lattice $M_3$, with elements $0$, $1$, $x$, $y$, and $z$ (where the join of any distinct elements of $\{x,y,z\}$ is $1$, and the meet is $0$). Let $M$ be the sublattice $\{0,x,1\}$. Then let $\Phi$ be the congruence in $M$ that identifies $0$ and $x$.

Let $\Psi$ be a congruence on $L$ that identifies $0$ and $x$. Then it must identify $0\vee y=y$ with $x\vee y=1$; similarly, it must identify $0\vee z = z$ with $x\vee z = 1$. Thus, $y$, $z$, and $1$ are identified in $\Psi$. That means that $z\wedge 1 = z$ must be identified with $z\wedge y = 0$, so all of $0$, $z$, $y$, and $1$ are identified in $\Psi$. That means that $x$ is identified with $1$ as well, so that $\Phi$ is a proper subcongruence of $\Psi|_M$. Thus, $M_3$ does not have the congruence extension property.

In fact, I *believe* (but don’t have access to my textbooks right now) that the Congruence Extension Property *precisely* characterizes the distributive lattices among all latices (see for instance the opening line of [this paper](https://msp.org/pjm/1971/38-3/pjm-v38-n3-p22-s.pdf) ) which would give an affirmative answer to your final question.

Answer (score 1):

If a lattice $L$ has the pentagon $N_5$ as a sublattice ($N_5=\{0,a,b,c,1\}$, with $0<a<b<1$, $0<c<1$, $a\wedge c=b\wedge c=0$ and $a\vee c=b\vee c=1$), then $L$ doesn't have the CEP, because the chain $\{0,a,b,1\}$ is a sublattice where
$$\theta(0,a)=\{0,a\}^2\cup\{(b,b),(1,1)\},$$
but in $N_5$, if $0\theta a$ then $c\theta 1$, and so $0\theta b$, and so
$$\theta_L(0,a)\supseteq\{0,a,b\}^2.$$
So there is no congruence of $L$ that restricts to $\theta(0,a)$ in $\{0,a,b,1\}$.

This together with the answer of Arturo Magidin shows that a lattice has the CEP iff it is distributive.